# Should I keep or remove random effects?

Tags: random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, generalized-least-squares, mixed-model

After attempting to produce a linear mixed model, I was left with a great deal of heterogeneity.

```
lme1 <- lme(Average.payoff ~ Game + Type + Others.Type + Game:Type + 
  Game:Others.Type + Type:Others.Type, random=~1|Subjects, method="REML", 
  data=Subjectsm1)
```

The response term `Average.payoff` is continuous, whilst all explanatory variables are binary.

When I look to validate, I can clearly see that the spread of the residuals decreases with the larger fitted values.

I decided alternatively to see what would happen if I just fit using `gls()`.

```
gls1 <- gls(Average.payoff ~ Game + Type + Others.Type + Game:Type + 
  Game:Others.Type + Type:Others.Type, method="REML", data=Subjectsm1)
anova(lme1, gls1)
#
#         Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test   L.Ratio p-value
#    lme1     1  9 67.81805 81.28662 -24.90902                         
#    gls1     2  8 66.14661 78.11867 -25.07330 1 vs 2 0.3285588  0.5665
```

As you can see  the `gls()` model gives a better fit than the `lme()` model. Even though I know from the experimental design that I have random effects, am I justified to remove them from the model if the fit is better without them?

Comment: How do you conclude that the "gls model" has a better fit? If you base your decision on AIC, then be aware that this MIGHT be dangerous. Indeed, "lme" and "gls" do not necessarily use the same log-likelihood: it may be that one of them left all additive constants out of the log-likelihood while the other include them; and this would compromise the comparison of AIC's.

Comment: No, you aren't, unless you can show that the assumptions of gls are met.  Usually, the reason for adapting a mixed model is that the assumptions of other models are not met.

Comment: @Jonathan as an aside, you don't need all those extra terms in the model since `R` will automatically expand interactions specified with a `*` (eg. `lm(y ~ x*z)` is the same as `lm(y ~ x + z + x:z)` and helps make the code a little easier to follow).

Comment: @ocram I used both AIC and loglik. I have read elsewhere that the gls() and lme() likelihoods are the same (but they are not for lm()).Bearing in mind the experiment involved 20 subjects, for each subject I have two samples, one where Others.Type=0 and one where Others.Type=1, do you have any further thoughts??

Comment: @smillig I did this because I did not want to include the 3-way interaction which would result from the code Type:Others.Type:Game   as I have read to avoid 3-way interactions.....any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have another related question here.....http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34932/varident-in-a-lme-model if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jonathan The model you want is `Average.payoff ~ Game*Type + Game*Others.Type + Type*Others.Type` which won't have any three-way interactions.

Answer (score 2):

An initial issue: when estimating the final parameters of a ME model, the restricted maximum likelihood (ReML) is used; as you have already done. ReML tries practically to find linear combinations of the responses, $k$, such that $k^TX= 0$ and thus to exclude any fixed terms parameters from the likelihood function ($X$ : $n\times p$ model matrix). However, ML should be used for the model selection procedure as the theory for model comparisons is based on ML estimation. As ReML will try to transform the fixed effect responses in the manner described above, this would lead to a series of different transformations for each model setting, making them incomparable. Therefore one should use ML estimators if likelihood ratio tests are to be employed (AIC etc.).

(Chapt.4 in Applied Longitudinal Analysis by Fitzmaurice et al. (towards the end of section 4.5 - I have the book but I just checked it and that section seems available in Google books also.))

Comment: thanks, strangely the book I am heavily using (Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R by Alain Zuur) says that I SHOULD be using REML for log likelihood ratio testing. I have though read other sources that agree with your suggestion. Is this a debated topic??

Comment: Em... not really debated... Putted simply (and paraphrasing Julian Faraway's "Extending the Linear Model with R", section 8.4) : If you compare two LME models with different fixed effects, the linear combinations, $k$, of them will be different and the obtained maximum likelihoods will be incomparable. I haven't seen Zuur's book but are you sure he is referring to model comparison? In your case it is a bit shady cause you have actually the same $X$ matrix in the LME and the GLS model but even then you assume uniqueness of $k$.

Comment: I too am using the ecology book and I think you should check as it says for testing fixed effects using use ML specifically when using the log likelihood test. As mine is an e-book I can not give you the page number. The REML should be run when you are happy with your fixed effects model.